# Having Problems On Organizing Code In Packages

Tags: java, android, eclipse

On my Android project I have the main `Activity` called `TestFIO`, which is in the package `org.testing.file.io.main`, and I tried to keep it clear and sent all the functions I had to a new class called `FileManipulator`, which is located at `org.testing.file.io.main.manipulator`. Here is how the `FileManipulator` class looks like:

```
package org.testing.file.io.main.manipulator;

// imports here

public class FileManipulator extends TestFIO {
    public String readFileFromCard(String location) {
        // some code here
    }

    // more functions here
}
```

And here is an example of `TestFIO`:

```
// header with package and imports

import org.testing.file.io.main.manipulator.FileManipulator;

public class TestFIO extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final String[] fileString = readFileFromCard(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "test.txt");
    }
}
```

The problem is that Eclipse is underlining `readFileFromCard` and showing the following error:

[image: Eclipse Error Dialog]

What am I doing wrong or how is the correct way to organize my code in packages?

*PS: Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm coming from iOS development.*

Comment: You are calling a Child's method in your Parent Class and its a violation of inheritance Rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compile problem is because you're trying to call a method defined in a subclass from the superclass. Inheritance doesn't work that way; subclasses inherit all public and protected methods from the superclass, but superclasses don't know anything about the methods of their subclasses.

Additionally, it doesn't seem reasonable to have `FileManipulator` extend your `Activity` class. Does `FileManipulator` pass the "is-a" test, in other words, is it a kind of `Activity`? It seems more like it's a "helper" class that the `Activity` will use to do its work. In that case, `FileManipulator` should not extend `TestFIO` but rather be stand-alone, created by `TestFIO`.

Comment: What should I do for my class to work on the `Activity` class? `FileManipulator` uses `getBaseContext()` to show up a `Toast` so I extended the `Activity`.   *Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm coming from iOS development.*

Comment: There are a couple of ways to get a "helper" class to invoke UI changes. The simplest is to just pass the instance of `Activity` when you create the `FileManipulator`, but there's a caveat to that simple solution: you can only invoke methods that change the UI from the thread that created the UI (sometimes called the "UI Thread"). Depending on how FileManipulator is being used, that might be OK in your app or might cause exceptions.

Comment: A more robust but slightly more complex solution would be to make the "helper" class an `AnsycTask` instead. Here is a good tutorial about `AyncTask` and some other options: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Answer (score 1):

I see TestFIO is parent class, FileManipulator is child class according to your code.
Then you can't call child class' method, you need a instance of FileManipulator.
Am I wrong?